# Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Find $E^s,E^u$ and $E^c$ of the linear system $x'=Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0  \\    1 & 0 \\    \end{pmatrix}$. Find the stable, unstable and center subspaces $E^s,E^u$ and $E^c$ of the linear system $x'=Ax$.

I've found the eigenvalues: $\lambda^2=0$ therefore $\lambda=0$. Thus the eigenvector is $v=(0,1)^T$ (Solving the system I obtained $v_1=0$ and $v_2$ is any arbitrary number) and finally $E^c=span\{(0,1)\}, E^s=\{0\}=E^u$

However in the answers from the book says that $E^c=\mathbb R^2$ and I think it's wrong OR  am I wrong?

Comment: This matrix only has on eigenvalue as you say, you are right.

Comment: @Mathematician42 :) ok thank you

Comment: I think i saw a theorem stating that direct sum of those three invariant subspaces is in fact the space ($\mathbb{R}^2$ in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You noticed correctly that $\lambda=0$ is the sole eigenvalue. Its algebraic multiplicity is two and its geometric multiplicity is one, as it can be already be seen from the non-diagonal Jordan normal form of $A$. Hence $E^c$ consists of the eigenvector to $\lambda=0$ **AND** the [generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector), which has to be additionally computed.

But as the generalized eigenvector will be linearly independent to the eigenvector, we know that $E^c$ will span the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence the dimension formula
$E^c \oplus E^u \oplus E^s=\mathbb{R}^2$
is indeed correct.